# vector autoregression where one of the dependent variable's current values determines the other dependent variables

Tags: time-series, econometrics, structural-equation-modeling, vector-autoregression

Take the following regressions:

1. y1 = a1+ d1*y3+ lag(Y)B1 + XG1 + u1
2. y2 = a2 + d2*y3+ lag(Y)B2 + XG2 + u2
3. y3 = a3 + d3*y3+ lag(Y)B3 + XG3 + u3

where Y = [y1, y2, y3] is a time-ordered matrix of data, terms "a" are intercepts, X is a matrix of covariates, B and G are vectors of coefficients, and u are error terms.  lag(.) is the one-period lag operator.

Give the solution to the coefficient matrix [a, d, B, G] such that d3 = 0

I seem to have stumped chatgpt :D

Is this even feasible using stacked OLS (probably with some clever weighting?), or would I need to use a constrained optimizer?